# Не работает javascript с handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars

Скажите пожалуйста  было у вас такое, что с использованием handlebars js у вас не работали некоторые элементы javascript на клиенте? У меня не хочет брать значения из поля ни с использованием jQuery ни чистого javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Handlebars тут не причем. Основная его задача (как и любого другого шаблонизатора) преобразовать ваш шаблон и данные в строку разметки. Что вы будете делать с этой строкой дальше зависит только от вас.

Как следствие, Handlebars никак не связан с DOM, поэтому никак на ваши элементы формы влиять не может. Ищете проблему где-то еще.

Comment: после его использования возникла такая проблема (или может где другое натупив) - использую getElementById().value или $('').val() получаю пустую ленту. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В чем угодно, но точно не в самом handlebars. Думаю вам для начала нужно составить [mcve] и постепенно локализовывать вашу проблему. Иначе - это все гадание на кофейной гуще